# How to generate a range of random number with fixed value in sql

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I am running the following code. For every execution I am getting the result of my query. But for every execution It's giving me different random value of SUPPLIER_ID. I want the value of SUPPLIER_ID to be fixed every time. Please help me with this.

```
SELECT
    T.*,
    C.*,
    LC.SUPPLIER_NAME,
    L.LOCAL_COMMODITY_DESC,
    CASE WHEN C.INVOICE_DESCRIPTION IS NULL
    THEN 'NO'
    ELSE 'YES' END AS DEPEND_OTHER
FROM OYSTER_WEB3.TRANSACTION T,
Local_Feed_Commodity_Map L,
OYSTER3.CAT_RULE_MV C,
OYSTER3.LOCAL_COMMON_SUPPLIER_MAP LC
    WHERE
    C.CAT_RULE_ID=T.CAT_RULE_ID
    AND
    C.DATA_FEED_CODE=LC.DATA_FEED_CODE
    AND
    T.SUPPLIER_CODE=C.LOCAL_SUPPLIER_CODE
    AND
    C.LOCAL_SUPPLIER_CODE=LC.SUPPLIER_CODE
    AND
    T.DATA_FEED_CODE=L.DATA_FEED_CODE
    AND
    C.LOCAL_COMMODITY_CODE=L.LOCAL_COMMODITY_CODE
    AND
    L.Local_Commodity_Code =         (SUBSTR(T.LOCAL_COMMODITY_CODE,1,INSTR(T.LOCAL_COMMODITY_CODE,'~')-1))
    AND T.TRANSACTION_DATE>='01-JAN-09'
    AND LC.SUPPLIER_ID IN
    (select trunc(dbms_random.VALUE(21852,2268730)) num from dual CONNECT BY LEVEL<=200);
```

Comment: How can it be fixed if it's random? Do you mean you want to temporarily make it consistent for testing, say?

Comment: Why dont you use a number of your choosing if you want the same number every time?

Comment: It can be fixed. I know it can be fixed using SEED. But I am unable to do it.The same sequence of random no. with same value can be generated every time.

Comment: @user3231684 - I don't understand; if you know it can be fixed with `SEED` then what is the issue? What does 'I am unable to do it' mean - you don't know how to call it, or it doesn't seem to be doing what you want? Are you calling it with the same seed value before each execution of your query?

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to generate pseudo-random numbers, using `rownum`.  You need to put your current query in a CTE (using `with`) or a subquery and generate `rownum` as a column name (say `seqnum`) with an `order by` clause (so it always produces the same results):

```
select rownum as seqnum . . .
order by <whatever>
```

Then in the outer query you can use `seqnum` for selecting rows.  For instance, if you wanted about 10%, you could do something like:

```
 mod(seqnum*101-87, 101) = 17;
```

I just use an expression containing prime numbers.  You can make a more complicated expression if you like.

This actually gives an 1-out-of-n sample.  For many purposes, such a sample is as good as or even better than a random sample.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure In understand why you would want a fixed range of random numbers, but if you do, you'll need to seed it. Normally two calls will get different results:

```
select trunc(dbms_random.VALUE(21852,2268730)) num from dual CONNECT BY LEVEL<=5;

       NUM
----------
   1691967 
   1536691 
    221687 
   1925527 
    793133 

select trunc(dbms_random.VALUE(21852,2268730)) num from dual CONNECT BY LEVEL<=5;

       NUM
----------
   1316523 
   1121136 
   1011501 
    242015 
   2182176
```

If you [reset the seed value](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_random.htm#i996798) before each call you'll get the same results:

```
exec dbms_random.seed(42);
select trunc(dbms_random.VALUE(21852,2268730)) num from dual CONNECT BY LEVEL<=5;

       NUM
----------
    195911 
   1291100 
   1478849 
   1426372 
    784607 

exec dbms_random.seed(42);
select trunc(dbms_random.VALUE(21852,2268730)) num from dual CONNECT BY LEVEL<=5;

       NUM
----------
    195911 
   1291100 
   1478849 
   1426372 
    784607
```

The [operational notes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_random.htm#i999084) explains:

> `DBMS_RANDOM` can be explicitly initialized, but does not need to be
>   initialized before calling the random number generator. It will
>   automatically initialize with the date, userid, and process id if no
>   explicit initialization is performed.
>
> If this package is seeded twice with the same seed, then accessed in
>   the same way, it will produce the same results in both cases.
>
> In some cases, such as when testing, you may want the sequence of
>   random numbers to be the same on every run. In that case, you seed the
>   generator with a constant value by calling one of the overloads of
>   `DBMS_RANDOM.SEED`. To produce different output for every run, simply to
>   omit the call to "Seed" and the system will choose a suitable seed for
>   you.